# "Injecting" data into an Android spinner being populated with an SQLite Cursor?

Tags: android, cursor, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I am using an SQLite Cursor to grab all the records I require from my table. I am using SimpleCursorAdapter to create multi-column Spinner using the Cursor.

While most values can be grabbed in this Cursor (5 columns, 4 come from the Cursor, 1 is calculated), I need to run a method to calculate a special figure (which is a Double). I would like to display this special figure in the Spinner above in the last column (5) and therefore I need to "inject" this special figure into the Adapter somehow.

Can someone please push me in the right direction?

TL;DR; Cursor grabs 80% of the data I need (5 columns, 4 come from the Cursor, 1 is calculated), I need to combine this with 1 special figure I calculate in a method (it returns a Double) and display this all in a Spinner as a multi-column spinner using SimpleCursorAdapter.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You need to show code and layout of what you've tried already. It's difficult to advise without them. I'd start by implementing `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder` on my `Activity`. Then, in the `bindView(...)` method get the data from the 4 columns of the `Cursor`, do whatever you need to do and then set the value of the 5th column in the supplied `View`.